# C# MySQL sum InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I have a query where I try to fetch the sum value but I get the InvalidCastException.

My query is:

```
SELECT e.clockNr,e.firstName,e.LastName,e.unionName,i.points 
FROM ( 
    SELECT employee.clockNr AS clockNr,
           employee.firstName AS firstName,
           employee.lastName AS lastName,
           Unions.name AS unionName 
           FROM employee,Unions 
           WHERE employee.active=1 AND employee.unionId = unions.id  
           GROUP BY employee.clockNr 
     ) e LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT infraction.clockNr AS clockNr, 
           CAST(SUM(Infraction.points) AS SIGNED) AS points 
           FROM infraction 
           WHERE infraction.infractionDate >=@startDate 
           AND infraction.infractionDate <=@endDate 
           GROUP BY infraction.clockNr 
     ) i ON e.clockNr = i.clockNr 
ORDER BY e.clockNr ASC
```

It is the 'points' column where it goes wrong.
I have added the CAST to SIGNED but this is not helping.

The way I read out the column is:

```
int iGetPoints = Convert.ToInt32(reportReader["points"]);
```

Also tried:

```
int iGetPoints = (int)reportReader["points"];
```

But both raise the InvalidCastException.
The query is tested in PHPMyAdmin and working fine there.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong or give me a hint where to look for?

Comment: What is the datatype of `points` column

Comment: It is an INT. I just tried to parse it as string and then convert to an int and that is working for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `points` column is part of the left join, it can be null. I'm assuming that's the problem here. You'll need to test for null to avoid the cast exception:

```
// Note: this is for DataTableReader; see below for MySQL data reader
int iGetPoints = 0;
if (!reportReader.IsDBNull(reportReader.DBOrdinal("points"))) {
   iGetPoints = Convert.ToInt32(reportReader["points"]);
}
```

The `IsDBNull` method requires the index of the column name (it won't work with the name), hence the call to `DBOrdinal` to get the index from the name.

---

*Note:* the answer above will work for the "generic" `System.Data.DataTableReader` class, but not for the MySQL data reader. Gerard posted the changes needed for the MySQL reader in the comments below. They are:

```
int iGetPoints = 0;
if (reportReader["points"] != DBNull.Value) {
   iGetPoints = Convert.ToInt32(reportReader["points"]);
}
```

Comment: That is a good points, only the MySQL datareader is not familiar with DBOrdinal?

Comment: This does the trick: 
    int iGetPoints = 0;
    if (reportReader["points"] != DBNull.Value) {
        iGetPoints = Convert.ToInt32(reportReader["points"]);
    }

Comment: Thanks Gerard, and good catch! I've updated my answer to include your code for the MySQL data reader; I think a lot of folks will benefit from it :)